# transform a formula for doubling time

Tags: logarithms, transformation

I have a problem with transforming a formula for doubling time.  It has two variables: increase (i) and number of periods (p).

The original formula: $p = \frac{\log(2)}{\log (1+i)}$.

When I enter $i = 0.05$, it correctly calculates $p = 14.207$.

Now I'm trying to make a formula for "increase".  I transformed it to: $i = 10^{\frac{\log(2)}{p}} - 1.$  When I enter $14.207$ periods, it gives me a increase = $0.1189$ (and not $0.05$).  Where's my mistake?

The transformations I did:

$p = \frac{\log(2)}{\log (1+i)}$

$\log(1+i) = \frac{\log(2)}{p}$

$1+i = 10^{\frac{\log(2)}{p}}$

$i = 10^{\frac{\log(2)}{p}} - 1$

It gives a wrong answer... Do you see where I made a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is using logarithm base $e$.  That didn't matter in the first formula, because the difference was cancelled by the two logarithms.
Two solutions: 1) there might be a logarithm spelt 'log10' instead of 'log'
Or, 2) you could use $\exp(\log(2)/p)-1$

Comment: I tried the latter solution and it works, thank you.